# "New feature" email notification tells me I signed up, but I did not!

Tags: bug, email, survey-2017

I just received the "new feature" notification for the developer survey 2017. The footer says:

> You’re receiving this email because you signed up for New Features on Stack Overflow.

[image]

That's a lie, I tell you, A LIE :-)

I think I was "opted in" by default. The footer should not say anything (and besides, it *doesn't need to say anything of the sort, so why bother?*).

Furthermore, when I click the unsubscribe link I get to this page:

[image]

where the "dismiss" link does not work, because there's a bug in the page's javascript.

Finally: how is the survey a "New feature"? The email is a general announcement, but please don't call it a new feature, because that's not the kind of content I'd expect to receive if I subscribed to the "New feature" email list in the first place.

Comment: Maybe the new feature is that the survey is sent out on the New Features list. *meta hands*

Comment: (They're sort of like jazz hands I guess)

Comment: Related (cross-site, see comments): *[Why is Stack Exchange using my old email address?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292914)*

Comment: @JasonC Probably more like a reference to jazz hands... but, I follow. :-)

Comment: @jpaugh *jazz-hands hands*

Comment: Recommend fixing this Right Quick Like. I have a *special* hatred of emails telling me I signed up for them when I didn't. Almost no matter who they're from, they get marked as spam. I can't be the only one...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, I made an exception in this case, but I totally do the same: unsubscribe and mark as spam, no ifs, no buts.